# One to Many - Calculated Column

Tags: ssas, dax

I am trying to teach myself the new Tabular model for SQL 2012 SSAS to handle some analytic reports that were previously handled in (slow) stored procedures.

I've made decent progress on most of it, just figuring out how things work and how to add the calculations I need but I have been banging my head against the following:

I have a table that has file information -- it has:
ID
FileName
CurrentStatus
UploadedBy

And then a table that has statuses that the file went through (a many relationship to the file table):

FileID
StatusID
TimeStamp

What I'm trying to do is to add a calculated column to the File table that returns the TimeStamp information when a file was in a particular status. ie: StatusID=100 is uploaded. I want to add a calculated column called UploadedDate on the File table that has the associated TimeStamp information from the FileStatus table.

It seems like this should be doable with DAX but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. Any ideas out there?

In advance, many thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula that should work for what you want to do...

```
=MAXX(
    CALCULATETABLE(
         'FileStatus'
        ,'FileStatus'[StatusID] = 100
    )
    ,'FileStatus'[TimeStamp]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming each file can only be in each status once (there is only one row per FileID that has StatusID 100). I believe you can just use a lookupvalue formula.  The formula for your UploadedDate calculated column would be something like

```
=LOOKUPVALUE(FileStatus[Timestamp], File[FileID], FileStatus[FileID], FileStatus[StatusID], 100)
```

Here's the [MSDN description of LOOKUPVALUE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492170.aspx). You provide the column containing the value you want returned, the column you want to search, and the value you are searching for. You can add multiple criteria to your lookup table. Here's a [blog post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492170.aspx) that contains a good example.